# How do I stop all running apps in the Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Device: Samsung Galaxy S3
Android: 4.1.1

I need to stop all running apps for an app, but how do I do that with one click? Is it safe?  Does the S3 have a tool?

Comment: Question is: What makes you need that? Android takes care pretty well to clean up if ressources are required. Task killing is rather contra-productive. If you'ld add some background, there might be better approaches to your goal -- and your current question might turn out being a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/192154) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Long-press the home button.
You should see something similar below.
*NOTE: It is from a Samsung Galaxy S4, but S3 should have it also.*
Then, click the 3rd icon (lower right).

YES, it is safe. It will close all open apps.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for lager variant)</sup>

**UPDATE #1:** Just to clarify Izzy's comment, he's *partially* right. Clicking the button will not close all running apps, but it will close all apps have you have manually opened. e.g. If you opened 3 different browsers, and clicked the button above, those 3 browsers would close. However, it will not close background processes / services that are running (e.g. AdBlock, aCalendar+, etc)

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, geff: but that will *not* close *all open* apps. It will only remove your recently-used apps from the list and kindly ask them to "calm down" (see also [Do applications that remain in Recent Apps list take up resources?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47652/16575)). Even if the additional button Samsung has placed there does kill the apps, this only handles "recently used", not necessarily "currently running". See *Settings->Apps->Running* to compare. Please correct me if this general rule is not valid for Samsung devices ;)

Comment: @Izzy Added Update#1 so that it's a bit clearer

Comment: Yepp, that fits better. Though that list is still named "recent apps" (and in older Android versions was limited to 6 or 9 entries), my experience with ICS/JB matches your description (apps are kept here until the user "swipes them out" explicitly). And that "kill button" (as well as the others visible in your screenshot) seem to be a Samsung extension to merge in a kind of task manager :) // Thanks for your update, geff -- much clearer now!

Comment: @Izzy After clearing my list, it says "No recent apps". So yeah, it is still the recent apps list.

Comment: Exactly. So to make your answer complete (on-board solutions), you might want to add the *Settings->Apps->Running* list, where one can walk each entry and "force stop" the corresponding apps/services. But that's even less "one click" then the "recent" list ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a task manager or a task killer app like [Advanced Task Killer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted your Android then ['Greenify'](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) is your answer !

It will help to hibernate all running services/apps/processes and free up resources.